# Не удаётся установить Microsoft SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

Здраствуйте, не удаётся установить SQL Server 2022. При установке приложения выскакивает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить.

Журнал:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Ошибка: дополнительные сведения см. ниже
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551
  Exit facility code:            1211
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  Не удалось найти раздел реестра "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\160\ConfigurationState".
  Start time:                    2023-06-08 21:46:34
  End time:                      2023-06-08 21:47:05
  Requested action:              Install
  Exception help link:           https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=0xF96176E5%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401&EvtType=0xF96176E5%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, а затем запустите процесс установки еще раз.
  Next step for Writer:          Установка SQL Server была отменена до завершения операции. Запустите процесс установки еще раз.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  DESKTOP-4013J22
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Майкрософт Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19045)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     Россия
  OS language:                   русский (Россия)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64-разрядная версия
  OS clustered:                  Нет

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2022 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2022
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       16
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\SQL2022\Developer_RUS\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

Product Update Status:
Пользователь выбрал не включать обновления продукта.

Примечание. Ознакомьтесь с условиями лицензии на программное обеспечение Microsoft SQL Server на странице aka.ms/useterms.

Параметры пользовательского ввода:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <пусто>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <пусто>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <пусто>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <пусто>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <пусто>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  AZUREARCPROXYSERVER:           <пусто>
  AZUREBILLEDEDITION:            
  AZUREREGION:                   <пусто>
  AZURERESOURCEGROUP:            <пусто>
  AZURESERVICEPRINCIPAL:         <пусто>
  AZURESERVICEPRINCIPALSECRET:   <пусто>
  AZURESUBSCRIPTIONID:           <пусто>
  AZURETENANTID:                 <пусто>
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230608_214634\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           false
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <пусто>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <пусто>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <пусто>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <пусто>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <пусто>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              true
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <пусто>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <пусто>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <пусто>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <пусто>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <пусто>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <пусто>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <пусто>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <пусто>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <пусто>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <пусто>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <пусто>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <пусто>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <пусто>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <пусто>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <пусто>
  PID:                           *****
  PRODUCTCOVEREDBYSA:            false
  QUIET:                         true
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  SAPWD:                         <пусто>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <пусто>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <пусто>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
  SQLMAXDOP:                     8
  SQLMAXMEMORY:                  2147483647
  SQLMINMEMORY:                  0
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <пусто>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-4013J22\Vsevolod
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <пусто>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <пусто>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            8
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <пусто>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <пусто>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <пусто>
  SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 false
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230608_214634\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Службы ядра СУБД
  Status:                        Сбой
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка при установке компонента.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, а затем запустите процесс установки еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230608_214634\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Недопустимый аргумент командной строки. За справкой по использованию командной строки обратитесь к пакету SDK установщика Windows.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       Файлы поддержки программы установки
  Status:                        Пройдено

  Feature:                       Модуль записи SQL
  Status:                        Сбой
  Reason for failure:            Установка компонента отменена.
  Next Step:                     Установка SQL Server была отменена до завершения операции. Запустите процесс установки еще раз.

Rules with failures or warnings:

Global rules:
Предупреждение IsFirewallEnabled                Брандмауэр Windows включен. Чтобы обеспечить удаленный доступ, убедитесь, что открыты соответствующие порты. Сведения о портах, которые необходимо открыть для каждого из компонентов, см. в документации по правилам на странице https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2162127.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230608_214634\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
    Message: 
        Не удалось найти раздел реестра "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\160\ConfigurationState".
    HResult : 0x84bb0001
        FacilityCode : 1211 (4bb)
        ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
    Data: 
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.FeatureRegistration.SetFeatureFlag(String machine, String featureId, String flagName, String registryKey, Object flagState, RegistryView cpuView)
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.FeatureRegistration.SetFeatureConfigState(String featureId, ConfigurationState configState, String version, RegistryView cpuView)
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.UpgradeIncompleteFeatureConfigEventHandler.MarkFeatureConfigured(FeatureId featureId, ConfigActionScenario scenario, Dictionary`2 actionData, String instanceId, Boolean keepFailedState)
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.UpgradeIncompleteFeatureConfigEventHandler.FeatureConfigurationExecutionEventHandler(Object sender, FeatureConfigScenarioEventArgs eventArgs, Boolean runValidation, Boolean featureFailed)
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.UpgradeIncompleteFeatureConfigEventHandler.FeatureConfigurationExecutionEventHandler(Object sender, Object[] objectArray)
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.NotificationHandler.Invoke(Object notification, Object[] objectArray)
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.NotificationService.OnNotify(Object eventKey, Object notification, Object[] objectArray)
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.ConfigExtension.ConfigFeatureActionListener.InFeatureConfigurationExecutionEventHandler(ActionKey key, TextWriter loggingStream)
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionMetadata.NotifyInExecution(ActionKey actionRunning, TextWriter loggingStream)`введите сюда код`
        в Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
```